# network request failed react native on https image upload Android

Tags: android, react-native, fetch, multipath

I am trying to upload image through fetch api but getting **Network request failed** error on real device android.
I also tried lots of lots of suggestion from google but nothing worked for me.

my dependencies are:

```
"react-native": "0.62.0",
"axios": "^0.19.2",
"form-data": "^3.0.0",
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

my snippets for image uploading:

```
const imagePick = () => {
          const formData = new FormData();

        try {

            const options = {
                title: 'Select Avatar',
                storageOptions: {
                  skipBackup: true,
                  path: 'images',
                },
              };

            ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {

                formData.append('avatar', {
                    uri: response.uri,
                   type: response.type, 
                   name: response.fileName,
                 })

                fetch(url, { 
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
                    },
                    body: formData
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.status)
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                })

            });

        } catch (e) {
            toast("Unable to upload profile photo")
        }
      }
```

I am also using secure https url;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue but I guess this issue isn't related to axios library, instead it is because of the React Native itself.

As mentioned here, [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551#issuecomment-610652110), it is because of **Flipper**.

So till the time React Native works upon it, you can comment below mentioned line from MainApplication.java

initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());

**To comment**, put // in front of above line

//initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());

Comment: resolution in case of managed workflow like Expo ...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue for a long time. The answer is quite simple. The code works on iOS but interestingly was failing on android.

For android, change from:

```
formData.append('avatar', {
    uri: response.uri,
    type: response.type, 
    name: response.fileName,
})
```

to:

```
formData.append('avatar', {
    uri: response.uri,
    type: `image/${response.type}`, 
    name: response.fileName,
})
```

For me, the image mime type caused axios to fail. Works fine without the image mime type on iOS tho.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this when I was updating the packages used by a React Native app I built a while back. Turns out that this error occurs when I use axios **v0.27.2** (latest at the time of writing this) but the upload function works fine when I revert to the previously installed version which was(is) **v0.24.0**.

Hopefully this older version will hold the fort for someone else as well as we await the issue to be officially fixed. I find it too risky commenting out Flipper because I honestly don't know enough to know I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Fast travel to 2024, in my case, it was because the file upload API url constant I imported was in a wrong format so it was `undefined` and I have been making upload call with very much correct format and file to an `undefined` url which my backend api was working as expected as I tested it million times ... how smart I am. T_T

:table-flip